# Can I compile LESS files but not bundle them in Angular-cli?

Tags: less, angular-cli

I know how to include `.less` files into Angular 2 using `angular-cli`. This works great. However, I am after something a bit different.

We have *themes* that we would like to load dynamically. I would like to leverage `angular-cli` to *compile* the `.less` files, but **not bundle** them into the `index.html`.

Is that at all possible with `angular-cli`?

I first thought of putting them as *assets* but, those are not compiled. They are simply copied/served as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW,

I ended up keeping it simple. I just added a [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task to compile the `.less` files to `.css` into my `assets` folder. Since they are in `assets`, they are automatically picked up by the build process and are served automatically (but not embedded into the `index.html`).

I used both [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) and [less-plugin-clean-css](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css) in the task:

```js
const less = require('gulp-less');
const cleanLess = require('less-plugin-clean-css');

gulp.task('less', ()=>{
    gulp.src('./src/themes/*.less')
    .pipe(less({
        plugins: [new cleanLess()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/assets/themes'));
});
```